Proving Snell's law using Fermat's principle

I have to derive Snell's law using Fermat's principle that minimizes the time taken by the light to travel from A to B. Now let horizontal distance between A and B be $L$ and let horizontal distance between A and C be $x$. Let $d_1$ be vertical distance from A to C and let $d_2$ be the vertical distance from B to C. Also, $v_1$ be the velocity of light in air and $v_2$ be velocity of light in water. Then total time taken by the light to travel from A to C is by the function
$$ f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + d_1^2}}{v_1} + \frac{\sqrt{(L-x)^2 + d_2^2}}{v_2} $$
where  $x \in [0, L]$. Now, using Calculus, the first derivative is
$$ f'(x) = \frac{x}{v_1 \sqrt{x^2 + d_1^2}} - \frac{(L-x)}{v_2 \sqrt{(L-x)^2 + d_2^2}} $$
To find the critical point, we equate this to zero and solve
$$ \frac{x}{v_1 \sqrt{x^2 + d_1^2}} = \frac{(L-x)}{v_2 \sqrt{(L-x)^2 + d_2^2}} \cdots\cdots(1)$$
Most of the solutions I have seen then claim that this value of $x$ is where $f(x)$ achieves the minimum and then use trigonometric definitions to conclude that
$$ \frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{v_1} = \frac{\sin(\theta_2)}{v_2} $$
But this is incomplete. Since there is a closed interval $[0, L]$ here, we will need to evaluate $f(x)$ at the critical points and the endpoints to see where the function has a minima. So, how do I prove that the value of $x$ given by equation $(1)$ gives the minimum value for $f(x)$ ?

If you know from the solution that the minimum is expressed in terms of the horizontals and the diagonals, then doing the derivation in terms of the verticals and the singular horizontal is unlikely to be pretty.

@Daniel, so what approach do you suggest ?

I don't see the need to restrict domain to $[0,L]$ a priori, the square roots describe appropriate distances even if $x<0$ or $x>L$. Therefore, following Martin's argument, we have a convex function on $\mathbb R$, so it has a unique minimum (if it has one). Only now we should ask ourselves whether this minimum is achieved at a point in $(0,L)$ or not and the answer is that it is because, again following Martin's argument, $f'$ is negative at $0$, but positive at $L$, so by IVT it's $0$ at some $x^*\in(0,L)$.

$$
f'(0) =  - \frac{L}{v_2 \sqrt{L^2 + d_2^2}}
$$
is negative, so that $f(x) < f(0)$ for all $x$  in some interval $(0, \delta)$ and the minimum it not attained at $x=0$.
Similarly, $f'(L) > 0$ shows that the minimum it not attained at $x=L$.
Therefore $f$ attains it minimum at some point $x^*$ in the interior at the interval, and $f'(x^*) = 0$.
It is also not difficult to calculate that $f''(x) > 0$, i.e. $f'$ is strictly increasing (and $f$ is strictly convex). Therefore, $f$ has only one critical point in $(0, L)$.

Good point. But we will still need to prove that equation $(1)$ gives only one critical point.

@user9026: There can only be one critical point because $f'$ is strictly increasing.

Makes sense, Martin. Thanks

As pointed out in the comment by Ennar, its not necessary to restrict the domain to $[0, L]$. Now, we have
$$ f''(x) = \frac{d_1^2}{v_1 (\;x^2 + d_1^2 \;)^{3/2}} + \frac{d_2^2}{v_2 \left[\;(L-x)^2 + d_2^2 \;\right]^{3/2}}$$
As can be seen, $f''(x)$ is defined everywhere. This means that $f'(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, $f''(x) > 0$. So, $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$. It also follows that $f'(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Now, consider the closed interval $[0,L]$. $f'(x)$ is continuous on this interval. And $f'(0) < 0 < f'(L)$. So, using intermediate value theorem, it follows that there is some $c \in (0,L)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$. So, $f'(x)$ has a root in $(0,L)$. Which means that $f(x)$ has a critical point in $(0,L)$. But, since $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$, there is only one root for $f'(x)$. And $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x < c$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x > c$. This means that this critical point of $f(x)$ is where we have the absolute minima for $f(x)$. So, using the trigonometry, it follows from $f'(x) = 0$ that
$$ \frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{v_1} = \frac{\sin(\theta_2)}{v_2} $$
Thanks $\smile$
